# Stateflow chart and C Action Language. Set array values for give in output a vector in single step

Tags: c, arrays, simulink, stateflow

i'm sorry, maybe is a stupid question, but i have issue to set my array variable in a stateflow chart by using C Action Language.

Usually in c language i can put in my static array all the values with "   A[]={1,3,2};   " , but in stateflow chart, with C ActionLanguage how i can it? (in matlab language work, but i need in C)
I've defined my variable with output scope (becouse it is),  setted the size as 3 (i want an array of 3 elements), set First index as "0" and type int8.

If a want in output the array "1,2,3" i write " gates=[1,2,3]; " , i've tried also "gates=[1 2 3]", etc,  but  i receive syntax error.
What are my errors? 
i've read in this link: https://it.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/ug/operations-for-vectors-and-matrices.html

> Assign Values to All Elements of a Matrix In charts that use MATLAB as
>   the action language, you can use a single action to specify all of the
>   elements of a vector or matrix. For example, this action assigns each
>   element of the 2-by-3 matrix A to a different value: A = [1 2 3; 4 5
>   6]; In charts that use C as the action language, you can use scalar
>   expansion to set all of the elements of a vector or matrix to the same
>   value. Scalar expansion converts scalar data to match the dimensions
>   of vector or matrix data. For example, this action sets all of the
>   elements of the matrix A to 10 A=10;

but not explain how set different values in all the array, and also i need that the output from the stateflow chart is in a single step :(. 
in the image there is a step with a syntax error. Someone can explain me how i can solve?
[Stateflow chart screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqNlb.png)

thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are 2 ways I would do it:

1. Define the values for ex: g1 = [1 0 0]; g0 = [0,0,0] in MATLAB workspace. And then in your stateflow use the values like gates = ml.g1; This works with C action language.(attached image gives a preview of this method)
   [image]
2. Implement a for loop(maybe a graphical function or a MATLAB function) inside your chart, which is used to assign values to your output array.

Of the two, I think the first method is easier to deal with, if the no of values the variable 'gates' takes is limited. Else, go for method 2.

Comment: thank you gautam264, i've applied a workaround by using a index value for a controlled switch. i'm sure that the 1st metod is easier. i will try in i need the nex time :)